# grails 3 cobertura not showing line coverage

Tags: gradle, groovy, cobertura, grails3

`cobertura` config in my `build.gradle` is given below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       //respective repos...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.5.3"  
    }
}

apply plugin: "net.saliman.cobertura"

cobertura {
    coverageFormats = ['xml' ,'html']

    coverageExcludes = ['.*Application.*',
                        '.*BootStrap.*',
                        '.*UrlMappings.*']
}

test.finalizedBy(project.tasks.cobertura)
```

`cobertura` not showing line coverage for below function syntax. And this syntax was working fine with `grails 2.x` + `maven` + `cobertura` configuration.

```
def nameOfMethod () {
    //method body
}
```

if i define the above method as closure , like below,

```
def nameOfMethod = { 
    //method body
}
```

then line coverage is showing.

Is there anything I have to add in configuration? Or is this `cobertura` issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with java version , means the compiled byte code, with cobertura. Right now to make it work , i updated my build.gradle like below

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6
```